# PHP - Can't filter by month from MySQL Database Query

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I'm doing my Student work at my local collage and we have to create the whole website with given topic. I choose Parking Car Lot topic and I stuck. Stuck and don't know where to look for a issue. What I need to do is to filter my given year and month data from the Database, which looks like this:

[image: Database Table]

and my query, to sort data from this table looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(parking_time) AS "Amont", SUM(sum) AS "Sum" 

    FROM parking_info

    GROUP BY MONTH(parking_time), YEAR(parking_time).
```

and the output from this query:

[image: Output from following query]

So as you see, the user should choose the year and the month from DROPDOWN list to select the particular month to filter the data from MySQL Query. For example: if the user chooses **year** 2013 and **month** from dropdown october it should only output for the user what particular month info, which is **Amount** 4 / **Sum** 170. But in my case it doesn't output anything(as you can see in my webpage).

Basically I have **functions.php** file where I holding all the countings, filters and SQL queries. My **functions.php** file for this particular page looks like this:

```
<?php 



function cleanFilterArray($filters) {

    $new_filters = array();

    if ($filters) {

        foreach ($filters as $field => $data) {

            if ($data != '%%') {

                $new_filters[$field] = $data;

            }

        }

        return $new_filters;

    } else {

        return false;

    }

}



function get_months_in_LT()

{

    $months = array();

    $months[] = array(1, 'january');

    $months[] = array(2, 'february');

    $months[] = array(3, 'march');

    $months[] = array(4, 'april');

    $months[] = array(5, 'may');

    $months[] = array(6, 'june');

    $months[] = array(7, 'july');

    $months[] = array(8, 'august');

    $months[] = array(9, 'september');

    $months[] = array(10, 'october');

    $months[] = array(11, 'november');

    $months[] = array(12, 'december');



    return $months;

}

function get_month_in_LT($num)

{

    $months = get_months_in_LT();

    return $months[$num][1];

}

function get_month_report($filters) {



    $where = null;



    if ($filters) {

            $filters = cleanFilterArray($filters);



            foreach ($filters as $field => $data) {

                if (!empty($data)) {

                    $where .= $field.' \''.$data.'\' AND ';

                }

            }

            if ($where) {

                $where = 'WHERE '.substr($where, 0, -5); //removes last 'AND' and adds a 'WHERE' to the begining

            }

    }

    var_dump($where);

    var_dump($filters);

    $result = mysql_query('

    SELECT COUNT(parking_time) AS "Amont", SUM(sum) AS "Sum" 

    FROM parking_info

    GROUP BY MONTH(parking_time), YEAR(parking_time)

    '.$where.'

    ');



    $rows = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))

    {       

        $rows[] = $row; 

    }       



    return $rows;   

}

?>
```

And my actual page, which holds all the HTML and all the other stuff looks like this:

```
<?php 



include_once 'functions.php';



if (isset($_GET['submit']))

{

  $year = $_GET['year'];

  $month = $_GET['month'];

}

else

{

  $year = date('Y');

  $month = date('m');

}





if (isset($_GET['submit']))

{

  if (isset($year) && $year > (int) date('Y'))

  {

    $error = 'this years has not yet come!';

  }

  if (isset($month) && $month > (int) date('m'))

  {

    $error = 'this month has not yet come';

  }

  elseif (isset($year) && $year < 0)

  {

    $error = 'date cannot be negative';    

  }

  elseif (isset($month) && ($month < 1 || $month > 12))

  {

    $error = 'not a month';

  }    


}



if (isset($_GET['submit']))

{

  $year = $_GET['year'];

  $month = $_GET['month'];



  $filters = array(

    "parking_time LIKE" => '%'.$year.'%',

    "parking_time LIKE" => '%'.$month.'%'

  );



}


include_once 'mysql.php';

if (isset($_GET['submit']) && !isset($error)){

  $infos = get_month_report($filters);  

}

$months = get_months_in_LT();



var_dump($infos);

?>



<?php include_once 'header.php' ?>

    <h1>Month Report</h1>

    <div id="main">

      <p>How much per month was observed cars and what is the total amount of money collected</p>

      <?php 

        if (isset($error))

        {

          echo "<p class=\"error\">Klaida: $error</p>";

        }    

      ?>

      <form method="post">

        <table border="1"> 

          <tr>

            <th>Year<span style="color:red">*</span></th>

            <td><input type="text" name="year" value="<?php if (isset($year)) echo $year ?>" /></td>

          </tr>

          <tr>

            <th>Month</th>

            <td>

              <select name="month" style="width:100%">

                <?php 

                  foreach ($months as $montha)

                  {

                    if (isset($month) && $month == $montha[0])

                    {

                      echo "<option value=\"$montha[0]\" selected=\"selected\">$montha[1]</option>";

                    }

                    else

                    {

                      echo "<option value=\"$montha[0]\">$montha[1]</option>";

                    }

                  }

                ?>

              </select> 

            </td>

          </tr>

          <tr>

            <td colspan="2" class="search"><button type="submit" name="submit" style="width:100%">Search</button></td>

          </tr>

        </table>

      </form>

      <br />

      <br />

      <?php if (isset($_GET['submit']) && sizeof($error) == 0): ?>

      <table border="1"> 

        <tr>

          <th>Amount</th>

          <th>Sum, LT</th>

        </tr>

        <?php

          foreach ($infos as $info)

          {

            echo "<tr>";

            echo "<td>$info[0]</td>";

            echo "<td>$info[1]</td>";      

            echo "</tr>";

          }

          if (count($infos) == 0)

          {

            echo "<tr><td colspan=\"2\">Rezultatų nėra.</td></tr>";        

          }

        ?>

      </table>  

      <?php endif; ?>

      <br/>

      <br/>

      <br/>

      <br/>

    </div>

<?php include_once 'footer.php' ?>
```

Hope someone will understand what I actual need because I just stuck and don't know why this page doesn't ouput anything. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to output the info for _only_ the specified year and month, then you should filter the results with an according WHERE clause as well. And btw., your GROUPing seems to be the wrong way around, it should be by YEAR first, and then MONTH. And you have done no error control whatsoever to see if your query even succeeds or maybe is faulty, so go add that (and look up how to do that if you don’t know).

Comment: GROUP BY order doesn't matter (except, perhaps, when optimizing against indexes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the query you can use month and  year from your table column like following.

```
 Month(parking_time) = $month   and YEAR(parking_time) = $year
```

Now in your file where you are creating the query add these instead of comparing using like.

Comment: Sorry for my stupid head, but I can't get it where I should add these lines. Should I add these in my functions.php somewhere? EDIT: oh I see now, I will try it.

Comment: In your query where your are comparing month and year with user given data. I think you are making your query and comparing in $filters array ??

Comment: Yes I do it like this: if (isset($_GET['submit']))
{
 $year = $_GET['year'];
 $month = $_GET['month'];
 
 $filters = array(
  "parking_time LIKE" => '%'.$year.'%',
  "parking_time LIKE" => '%'.$month.'%'
 );
   
} 

but now I don't know how to implement your code to my $filters array. When I change it I get an error: " Can't use function return value in write context in ....... "

Comment: yes you have to change this because you cannot use a function like you are using LIKE. instead change your query.
and use this  $where = "Month(parking_time) = '$month'   and YEAR(parking_time) = '$year'". please modify it according to your requirements.

Comment: $where = " Month(parking_time) = '$month' and YEAR(parking_time) = '$year'". add this for where clause.

Comment: I think it working now. It seems like my filtering was messed up completelly. Thank you very much Maz :)